# Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'NYDStok.BarButtonItem' to 'DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItem'

Tags: c#, devexpress

I want to create a button in C# Devexpress. [This is the area where I want to add the button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkLBf.png)

But when I try to add it I get an error.My code is as below. As soon as the button is clicked, it saves the file with the day, month, year and instant time of that day. But because my button is not visible, these processes are not happening now. [I tried to add this button from another project to my own project. That's why I need help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAsoM.jpg)

```
        void PreviewForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintPreviewFormEx form = (PrintPreviewFormEx)sender;
        PrintPreviewBarItem item = (PrintPreviewBarItem)form.PrintBarManager.GetBarItemByCommand(PrintingSystemCommand.ExportFile);

        PopupMenu control = (PopupMenu)((DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem)(item)).DropDownControl;
        BarButtonItem barItem = new BarButtonItem();
        barItem.ItemClick += barItem_ItemClick;
        barItem.Caption = "TELEGRAM";
        control.AddItem(barItem);


    }
    async void barItem_ItemClick(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime Tarih = DateTime.Today.Date;
        if (vwMain.GetFocusedRowCellValue(clnUHTarih) != null)
            DateTime.TryParse(vwMain.GetFocusedRowCellValue(clnUHTarih).ToString(), out Tarih);



        PdfExportOptions pdfExportOptions = new PdfExportOptions()
        {
            PdfACompatibility = PdfACompatibility.PdfA1b

        };

        string pdfExportFile = @"C:\samet\" + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now).Replace(".", "").Replace(":", "").Replace(" ", "_") + ".pdf";
        // Export the report.
        rprGunSonu rpr = new rprGunSonu(pConn, Tarih.Date, clsAyarlar.SubeID);
        pt = new ReportPrintTool(rpr);
        rpr.ExportToPdf(pdfExportFile, pdfExportOptions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PopupMenu.AddItem()` [expects an object of type `DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItem`](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraBars.PopupMenuBase.AddItem(DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItem)).  You're passing it an object of type `NYDStok.BarButtonItem` (whatever that is).  Your `barItem` needs to be a `DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItem` instead.

For example:

```
var barItem = new DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItem();
barItem.ItemClick += barItem_ItemClick;
barItem.Caption = "TELEGRAM";
control.AddItem(barItem);
```

(Note that you'd also need to change your implementation of `barItem_ItemClick` to use `ItemClickEventArgs` instead of `ItemCheckEventArgs` in order to match the event signature.)

Comment: Yes, I changed it from BarButtonItem to BarItem and my error is gone.